# How to pass two javascript variables in my URL?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have the following code that updates the latbox/lngbox "form field" values on my page when the marker is dragged:

```
<!---Code the Address & Lat/Long into the Info window --->
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var account = document.getElementById('account').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            if (marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);

                if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
            }

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                // updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
                geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
                document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
                document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
            });
```

**Question:** How do I "pass those two values" to my URL below?

```
<!---Create the page to display the Account Name, Address, Geocode button to update page & Save button to save Lat/Long back into Salesforce --->
<div>
    <div align="center">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input name="account" type="hidden" id="account" value="<cfoutput>#URL.id1#</cfoutput>">
            <input name="address" type="hidden" id="address" value="<cfoutput>#URL.id2#</cfoutput>">
            <input type="button" value="Plot this customer using Physical Address" Title="Click to Map the Physical Address of Salesforce Account (if avl)"onclick="codeAddress()">

            New Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" >
            New Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="lngbox" name="lng" >

            <input type="button" name="updateAccountLatLng" id="updateAccountLatLng" value="Update Account?" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.mysalesforce.com/001U000000W2Xgx/e?<cfoutput>#URL.id1#</cfoutput>&00NU0000003BKlJ=javascript.latbox&00NU0000003BKlO=javascript.lngbox'">
        </form>
    </div>
```

I can get the JavaScript values to display dynamically in my form field/page, but I can't get the JavaScript values to pass into the URL string?

Comment: Dan, I'm trying to pass the lat & lng values into a url when the updateAccountLatLng "button" is clicked. (see my code line right above the /form)

Comment: If your existing code is populating the form fields, and the form has method = "get", how is this not a simple matter of submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by doing the following:

I ended up changing the form POST to GET (since get automatically forwarded the two form values for me in the URL)
The key was to add the unique Salesforce field names (name="00NU0000003BKlJ" & name="00NU0000003BKlO") to my form field properties so the GET would post the values.
Here is the updated form code:

```
<!---Create the page to display the Account Name, Address, Geocode button to      update page & Save button to save Lat/Long back into Salesforce --->
        <div>
        <div align="center">
        <!---When user clicks the submit button, use GET to open the record in    Salesforce and pass the new Lat/Lng values to the page --->
        <form method="get"  action="https://my.salesforcedomain.com/<cfoutput>#URL.id#  </cfoutput>/e?">
        <input name="account" type="hidden" id="account" value="<cfoutput>#URL.id1#</cfoutput>">
        <input name="address" type="hidden" id="address" value="<cfoutput>#URL.id2#</cfoutput>">
        <input type="button" value="Plot this customer using Physical Address" Title="Click to Map the Physical Address of Salesforce Account (if avl)"onclick="codeAddress()">


      <!---Checkbox to toggle Fiber layer on/off --->
        <input type="button" id="layer0" onClick="toggleLayer(0)" value="View Fiber" title="Click twice to overlay Fiber Map KML overlay(Click again to toggle on/off)">
        <input type="button" id="layer1" onClick="toggleLayer(1)" value="Buildings" title="Click twice to overlay Buildings Map KML overlay(Click again to toggle on/off)">
        <input type="button" id="layer2" onClick="toggleLayer(2)" value="Vaults" title="Click twice to overlay Vaults Map KML overlay(Click again to toggle on/off)">
        <input type="button" id="layer3" onClick="toggleLayer(3)" value="Proposed" title="Click twice to overlay Proposed Map KML overlay(Click again to toggle on/off)">
    </h2>New Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="00NU0000003BKlJ" >New Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="lngbox" name="00NU0000003BKlO" >
        <input type="submit" name="updateAccountLatLng" id="updateAccountLatLng" value="Update Salesforce Account?" title="Click here to update the new lat/lon values to your Salesforce account.">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in your codeAddress function you want a line at the end of the function that changes queryParams based on the lat/lon

something like ...

`` window.history.pushState('', 'title', window.location + `?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`) ``

Comment: Jon, your idea is the direction I was thinking of.. but how do I "combine" it with my line: onclick="window.location.href='https://www.mysalesforce.com/001U000000W2Xgx/e?<cfoutput>#URL.id1#</cfoutput>&00NU0000003BKlJ=javascript.latbox&00NU0000003BKlO=javascript.lngbox'">

Comment: Do you want the query params to be added when codeAddress() is called, or do you want it to update only when they click the second input? If #2, change the onclick=window.location.href to be a function that changes the window.history like above, and also does whatever else you need it to do

Comment: Yes, when the user clicks the last submit button. For some reason I could not get those two form field values to pass into my Salesforce page... driving me crazy.